# iOS App rejected by apple for non public API usage

Tags: ios

Apple rejected the free version of my app and I don't know where to start:

> Your app uses or references the following non-public APIs, which is a violation of the App Store Review Guidelines:
>   textFieldDidChange

I am sure I don't use textFieldDidChange in any way in my own code.

**Possible cause 1:**

I am using Eureka. https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka

Eureka defines and uses own methods named textFieldDidChange. These methods have nothing to do with Apple API.

These methods only happen to have the same name as non public apple API.

Eureka does not call apple API with this name.

Is it possible that an Apple engineer rejects an app because it uses the same method name as internal API?

My paid App uses exactly the same Eureka code and wasn't rejected.

**Possible cause 2**

The difference between the rejected and the non rejected App are two libraries:

1. PureLayout
2. AdMob

I have the complete sourecode of PureLayout. It doesn't use anything with textFieldDidChange in it.

AdMob (downloaded using cocoapods May 17th 2016) has a copyright notice from 2015. So I guess I'm using the same version as 10000s of apps. Any way to find out which version I'm using?

**tools**

I know I can use otool and nm.

But I don't know where I can find all the relevant files that I have to examine with otool and nm.

I have a complete git branch containing everything to reproduce everything of the submitted app.

Any hints where I can start? Is there any way to ask Apple whether they confused methods with the same name as internal API?

Target is iOS 8 + 9.

Comment: You already answered your question. Eureka is using a method with the same name as a private API used by Apple. They need to change their code.

Comment: thanks. I will suggest that to Eureka and will change the name locally in my project.

Comment: Isn't it quite radical to prohibit the use of names of *non-public* APIs in projects? This seems to mean that developers must learn about those names, even if they can't use them. Maybe this isn't even intended as the paid version passed and Apple's non-public API isn't actually used.

Comment: I thought the same as Felix. But you can be right or you can have success, but not both :-) So I changed my local version of Eureka.

Comment: @FelixDombek Apple has been known for having tight policies, where you post from the app is one of them (I'm sure it is to prevent abuse / syphoning out data from a user). Sucks that it affects legitimate uses, too.